# ansible: The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'variable' is undefined

Tags: ansible

I am writing ansible playbook, and set the below variable :

```
default_tz: 'ZONE="America/Los_Angeles"'
```

I am trying to add the above variable to a file, by using the below code
On the same playbook:

```
- name: configure time zone
  lineinfile:
   line: "{{ default_tz }}"
   dest: "/etc/sysconfig/clock"
```

I am getting the below error while running the playbook:

```
"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'default_tz' is undefined\
```

Comment: How exactly have you set the variable (i.e. in a `vars` block, with `set_fact` module, some where in the inventory)? Can you post the actual code you have used to set the variable relative to the task that is called it?

Comment: i set the variable in vars block

Comment: Well without any further code, there is nothing obviously wrong with what you are doing.  So if this is all in the same playbook, then the most likely issue is that you have more than one play in the playbook and are defining the variable in one, and calling it in another which won't work. Hard to know tho without seeing all the relevant code.

Comment: please post the whole playbook with vars mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare variable in the scope of variables. 
Like this:

`vars:
   default_tz: 'ZONE="America/Los_Angeles"'`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-a-playbook